# Does Yachiru ever come back?

Tags: bleach

In the *Bleach* anime, Yachiru disappears because she is Kenpachi's Spirit, but does she ever come back?

Answer (score 1):

There's no indication she comes back as a physical being in the manga (although she is Zarakai's zanpakuto spirit so he can talk to her at any time). In Ch 685 ten years after the conclusion of the Thousand Year Blood War Kenpachi bickers with Ikkaku and Yumichika while lost on their way to the appointment of the new captain of Squad 13 where Ikkaku is referred to as second in command which was Yachiru's seat before Quincies happened. Kenpachi himself then explains that his poor sense of direction was Yachiru's fault and now that she "isn't around no more" he won't get lost anymore... he says while lost... as usual...

Answer (score 0):

how to explain this.....
Yachiru is actually Kenpachi's sword Nozarashi. it is either this or she is a part of his spiritual powers. when you say that she is in Kenny's soul this is true, but he sucks at spiritual stuff, and probably couldn't talk to her if he tried